# Include span or HTML as input to Angular component

Tags: angular, angular-components

Let's say I have a component where the ts file looks something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() header: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

On my HTML page I then write something like:

```
<my-component header="Hello"></my-component>
```

And `Hello` will then be shown with whatever CSS I use. However, how can I pass like a `<span>` to this header input, if I were to emphasize a word or something, e.g:

```
<my-component header="Hello my <span>friend</span>"></my-component>
```

And then `friend` would get another `color`, another `font-weight` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `inputs` are used to pass small info to the component, like a name or a number. The structure of how and where this info is shown is up to the layout and style of the component. So you should implement something like:

In the my-component.component.html:

```
Hello my <span>{{header}}</span>
```

And when you use the component, pass the value of `header` like you did:

```
<my-component header="Hello"></my-component>
```

This way you can use `my-component.component.scss` file to style the text (and all your component layout) as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on Manuel answer, if you want to pass multiple HTML nodes (or components) to your MyComponent component, you can use https://angular.io/guide/content-projection.

This way, you can call your component this way :

```
<my-component>Hello <span>my friend</span></my-component>
```

And then in your MyComponent template, you can retrieve this *content* using the `<ng-content></ng-content>` tag.